# Is std::basic_format_string copyable and moveable?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

On cppreference.com I can't find any information about whether [`std::basic_format_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/basic_format_string) defines a copy or move constructor or if these don't exist.

When I look at [Microsoft's STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/7d5d8c32a7988f86c0f9e975559d1c7a3566f05e/stl/inc/format#L3699-L3721) implementation, it looks like the compiler-generated versions are simply available. Is this defined in the C++ standard?

Comment: Well it is a wrapper around string_view and that's copyable and movable (just won't take ownership of the underlying string).  C++ standard reference : https://eel.is/c++draft/format.fmt.string. Copy constructor is explicitly shown. So yes it is copyable and movable. (Move constructor will be implicitly generated, default constructor is implicitly deleted)

Comment: @PepijnKramer that link does not show a "copy constructor".  It shows a "converting constructor", and according to cppreference, `std::basic_format_string` can only be constructed from either a compile-time string or something is that convertible to `std::basic_string_view` (which `std::basic_format_string` is not).  Nowhere does cppreference or your standard reference claim that `basic_format_string` is copyable from another `basic_format_string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I stand corrected, I looked at it and  missed the part that basic_format_string is not convertible to a string_view. Me bad, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you have to [go directly to the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/format.fmt.string):

```
template<class charT, class... Args>
struct basic_format_string {
private:
  basic_string_view<charT> str;         // exposition only

public:
  template<class T> consteval basic_format_string(const T& s);
  basic_format_string(runtime-format-string<charT> s) noexcept : str(s.str) {}

  constexpr basic_string_view<charT> get() const noexcept { return str; }
};
```

In this definition of `basic_format_string`, there is no declared copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, so all of these special member functions are implicitly declared in accordance with the core language rules regarding special member functions. In this case since the only data member is of type `basic_string_view<charT>`, all four of the copy/move special member functions will simply copy/move that data member.